# Что то не так с указателями

Tags: c, указатели, память, структуры

В моей программе происходит ввод элементов структурного типа и ввод 2 чисел.
После собственно ввода в меню сверху у меня показывает статус , введены ли данные (ДА , НЕТ) проверяя, нет ли где NULL в указателе(если нет NULL ,  то выделялась память, а если выделялась память, то и данные записывались.)
Так вот, после записи данных, статус "НЕТ" не переходит в "ДА", я не могу понять в чем дело, возможно с указателями намудрил...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "locale.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

//Глобально задаем структуру
struct base
{
    int first;
    int second;
    int third;
} *list = NULL;

//Функции

//Проверка выделения памяти
void CheckMem(void *list);
//Ввод диапазона
void Range(int *n, int *N);
//Меню ввода данных через консоль
void ConsoleRecord(struct base *list, int *len,int *n,int *N);
//Запись элементов стр. типа через консоль
void ConsoleScan(struct base *list, int *len);
//Чистим мусор после ввода
void CleanStdin();


int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    //Диапазон
    int *n;
    n = NULL;
    int *N;
    N = NULL;
    //Длина массива стр. элементов
    int *len;
    len = NULL;

    char number;

    printf("Добро пожаловать.");
    do {
        printf("Выберите необходимый пункт:\n");
        printf("1) Запись данных с помощью консоли\n");
        printf("2) Запись данных с помощью текстового файла\n");
        printf("3) Выход\n");

        number = getchar();
        CleanStdin();

        switch(number){
        case '1':
            system("cls");
            ConsoleRecord(list, len, n, N);
            break;
        case '2':
            system("cls");
            printf("Еще не готово :(\n");
            break;
        case '3':
            break;
        default:
            system("cls");
            printf("Вы ничего не выбрали.\n");
            break;
        }
    } while(number != '3');

    //Освобождение памяти
    free(list);
    free(len);
    free(n);
    free(N);

    return 0;
}

void CheckMem(void *p) {
    if (p == NULL) printf("Память не выделена. Аварийное завершение программы.\n"), system("pause"), exit(1);
}

void Range(int *n, int *N) {

    if (n == NULL) {
        n = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)), CheckMem(n);
        N = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)), CheckMem(N);
    }

    printf("Введите диапазон ОТ:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", n);
    CleanStdin();
    printf("Введите диапазон ДО:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", N);
    CleanStdin();
    printf("Ваш диапазон: %d-%d\n", *n, *N);
    system("pause");
    CleanStdin();
    system("cls");
}

void ConsoleRecord(struct base *list,int *len, int *n,int *N) {

    char number;

    printf("Вы выбрали запись данных с помощью консоли.");
    printf("\n------------------------------------------\n");
    do {
        printf("Диапазон: ");
        if (n == NULL) {
            printf("НЕТ");
        }
        else {
            printf("ДА");
        }

        printf(". Элементы структурного типа: ");
        if (len == NULL) {
            printf("НЕТ");
        }
        else {
            printf("ДА");
        }


        printf(".\n------------------------------------------\n");

        printf("Выберите необходимый пункт:\n");
        printf("1) Ввести элементы структурного типа\n");
        printf("2) Ввести диапазон\n");
        printf("3) Обработка структуры\n");
        printf("4) Выход в основное меню\n");

        number = getchar();
        CleanStdin();

        switch (number) {
        case '1':
            system("cls");
            ConsoleScan(list,len);
            break;
        case '2':
            system("cls");
            Range(n,N);
            break;
        case '3':
            system("cls");
            printf("Еще не готово.\n");
            break;
        case '4':
            system("cls");
            break;
        default:
            system("cls");
            printf("Вы ничего не выбрали.\n");
            break;

        }
    } while (number != '4');
}

void CleanStdin() {
    int c;
    do {
        c = getchar();
    } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

void ConsoleScan(struct base *list, int *len) {

    if (len == NULL) {
        len = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)), CheckMem(len);
    }
    else {
        printf("Идет перезапись элементов массива структурного типа.\n");
        free(list);
        return;
    }

    printf("Введите кол-во элементов структурного типа:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", len);
    CleanStdin();

    list = (struct base*)malloc((*len) * sizeof(struct base)), CheckMem(list);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < *len; i++) {
        printf("Введите поля %d-ого элемента массива структурного типа: ", i + 1);
        scanf_s("%d", &(list->first));
        scanf_s("%d", &(list->second));
        scanf_s("%d", &(list->third));
    }
    CleanStdin();
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Параметры функций являются их локальными переменными. Функции имеют дело с копиями значений переданных им аргументов.

Например,  если у вас есть программа следующего вида

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f( int *ptr )
{
    ptr = malloc( sizeof( int ) );

    printf( "Inside f ptr = %p\n", ( void * )ptr );
}

int main( void ) 
{
    int *p = NULL;

    printf( "Before f( p )  p = %p\n", ( void * )p );

    f( p );

    printf( "After f( p )  p = %p\n", ( void * )p );


    return 0;
}
```

то ее вывод на консоль будет иметь вид

```
Before f( p )  p = (nil)
Inside f ptr = 0x2ae3fe1af020
After f( p )  p = (nil)
```

То есть, как видно из вывода, переменная `p`, объявленная в `main` не изменилась после вызова функции `f`, так как функция имела дело с копией значения этой переменной. Вы можете представить функцию и ее вызов следующим образом

```
int *p = NULL;


f( p );

// ...

void f( /* int *ptr */ )
{
    int *ptr = p;

    ptr = malloc( sizeof( int ) );

    printf( "Inside f ptr = %p\n", ( void * )ptr );
}
```

В функции изменилось значение ее параметра `ptr`, который был инициализирован значением аргумента `p`. Значение же самого аргумента `p` не изменилось.

Или еще более простой пример. В нижеприведенной программе никакой функции не вызывается, но, формально вложенный блок кода можно рассматривать как тело некой предполагаемой функции. Объявленную переменную `y` в теле блока кода можно рассматривать как параметр функции. А объявленную до входа в блок кода переменную `x` можно рассматривать как аргумент функции.

В блоке кода переменная `y` инициализируется значением переменной `x`, а затем переписывается новым значением `25`. После выхода из блока кода переменная `Y` прекращает свое существование. Что касается переменной `x`, то ее собственное значение не было изменено.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    int x = 10;

    printf( "x = %d\n", x );

    //  Рассматривайте этот блок кода, как тело вызванной функции
    //  имеющей параметр `y`, и которой передается аргумент `x`
    {
        int y = x;

        y = 25;

        printf( "y = %d\n", y );
    }

    printf( "x = %d\n", x );

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
x = 10
y = 25
x = 10
```

Если вы хотите, чтобы менялось значение аргумента, то его надо передавать по ссылке. Например,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f( int **ptr )
{
    *ptr = malloc( sizeof( int ) );

    printf( "Inside f ptr = %p\n", ( void * )*ptr );
}

int main( void ) 
{
    int *p = NULL;

    printf( "Before f( p )  p = %p\n", ( void * )p );

    f( &p );

    printf( "After f( p )  p = %p\n", ( void * )p );

    free( p );   

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
Before f( p )  p = (nil)
Inside f ptr = 0x2b3135483020
After f( p )  p = 0x2b3135483020
```

Так как в функции теперь параметр объявлен как указатель на указатель, то значение исходного указателя меняется в функции.

Также лучше вместо функции `getchar` использовать функцию `scanf` в следующем виде

```
scanf( " %c", &number );
       ^^^^
```

Иначе функция `getchar` также будет считывать символы пробелов, что может привести не  к тому результату, который вы ожидаете.

Comment: Да, спасибо большое. Прошу прощения, что долго не принимал ответ как верный, забыл про него чуток.